# How do I prevent a user from sending more than one message in a channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
User 1: Hello!
User 1: How are you?
User 2: I'm good.
User 2: hbu
User 3: hey guys!
User 1: i'm doing fine
```

I'm trying to delete the second message from User 1 and User 2, so that any user can only send a single message. I was told to use `channel.history`, but I can't think of a way to compare the author's of the messages to make sure they aren't the same person.

This is what I want: I want to prevent double posting:

```
User 1: Hello! How are you?
User 2: I'm good, hbu.
User 3: hey guys!
User 1: i'm doing fine
```

I just don't know how to use `channel.history` to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `on_message()` event and set the channel history's limit to 2 for this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    recent_author = (await message.channel.history(limit=2).flatten())[1].author
    if message.author == recent_author:
        await message.delete()
```

The `history()` coroutine gets the newest messages first, unless specified otherwise, so you can set the limit to 2 to get the most recent message before the one the user just sent.

---

**References:**

- [`Messageable.history()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.history)
- [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author)
- [`Message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete)