# How do I make it so that a user can not post more than one message in a row, discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My question is similar to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247215/how-do-i-prevent-a-user-from-sending-more-than-one-message-in-a-channel), but the linked question is for discord.py, I am looking for an answer for discord,js.

Now the question: I am looking to create a counting channel (similar to the [Countr Bot](https://countr.xyz/#/)), and I would like to make it so that if a user double posts in a channel, the second message gets deleted. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean double posting with two separate messages? Or you want just to forbid users to post messages with more than one `\n`?

Comment: with 2 separate messages. I want to forbid a user from posting 2 messages in a row. I want user 1 and 2 to alternate messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's very not so hard to forbid the user to post messages in a certain text channel. But the real problem is, how to manage this task and balance the load.

There are two ways:

- (text) mute user
- edit its permission to post in a certain channel

And bot should have the necessary permissions for this operations.

Here is a simple example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.login('your token here').catch(e => console.error(e));

const buffer = new Set();

//listening for all the messages, actually you should listen for messages in a certain channel
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (buffer.size) {
   //unmute, or return permissions to normal for stored users.
   buffer.clear() //clear buffer set
  }
  buffer.add(message.author.id) //add user with latest message to buffer
  /**
   * your own code implementation of
   * muting or editing message.author.id permission
   * in a cerain channel, which should forbid him to post
   **/
})
```

Comment: I guess that would work. Is there something like `message.channel.history` in discord.js? or is that just in discord.py?

Comment: @nathen418 I haven't finished my answer yet, but I am working with `Discord.js`, I don't actually know what `message.channel.history` in `discord.py` does. But it's possible to receive message history for user.

Comment: Your example wouldn't work if the bot crashed or restarted, as `buffer` would be wiped out as a new set.

Comment: @OctagonalT yeap. But we also could take a look at the last sent message in the channel and add its author.id to set